# Finding a bisector hyperplane of two vector in n-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, plane-geometry

Suppose two vectors $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ in n-dimensional space. I want to find a hyperplane that bisects the angle between these two vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalize (really, they just need to be the same length):
$$
  \hat v_1 = \frac{v_1}{|v_1|},\quad
  \hat v_2 = \frac{v_2}{|v_2|}.
$$
Then $w = \hat v_2 - \hat v_1$ is normal to the hyperplane $H$ you want:
$$
  H = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \;:\; x\cdot w = 0\},
$$
where $\cdot$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by a bisector hyperplane. But assuming the standard metric of $\mathbb R^n$ I think that you are looking for the following construction:

- Normalize $v_1$ and $v_2$, defining $u_1:=\frac{v_1}{\parallel v_1 \parallel}$ and $u_2:=\frac{v_2}{\parallel v_2 \parallel}$
- Consider a basis $\{b_1,\ldots,b_{n-2}\}$ of the orthogonal complement to $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle$.
- The required hyperplande would be
  $$
  \langle b_1,\ldots,b_{n-2},u_1+u_2 \rangle
  $$

[image]